# Correct Schema.org itemtype for the related content

Tags: schema.org, related-content

I am defining the `itemtype` for reviews as follows:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <!-- Review content -->
    <aside itemprop="" itemscope itemtype="">
        Related content goes here
    </aside>
</div>
```

Which microdata should I use for the related content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using schema.org’s [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article), so you’ll have to use properties defined for this type (or proprietary properties in the form of absolute URIs).

`Article` doesn’t define a property for general relations, but there are properties for special relations:

- [`about`](http://schema.org/about), if it’s the subject matter of the `Article`
- [`citation`](http://schema.org/citation) if it’s a citation or reference of the `Article`
- [`comment`](http://schema.org/comment), if it’s a comment about the `Article`
- [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions), if it’s a reference from the `Article`
- [`review`](http://schema.org/review), if it’s a review of the `Article`

The type of the related content, well, depends on the related content. The choice may also restrict the use of the mentioned properties, as they typically expect a certain (general) type.